# AWS DynamoDB restrict access to an attribute-value in IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have an AWS DynamoDB table which consists of one key and some attributes.
AWS IAM allows to restrict the access to a specific key: [Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html).

But is it possible to "filter" by the value of an attribute?
For example:

"Allow access to all rows, where attribute_A = 1"

I didn't find anything like that after searching for hours. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you only have two options when restricting access via IAM:

1. Control access via Partition Key
2. Control access to attributes returned

It is not possible to restrict access via an attribute which isn't the Partition Key.

A workaround you could look into:

Leverage a GSI and use the Partition Key as your desired attribute you wish to filter by. You can restrict a user to only query the given Index and filter by the Partition Key of the GSI.

Read more here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

HTH